# Nullable DatePicker for Xamarin MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have requirement for nullable datepicker for xamarin maui. I can find the solutions for Xamarin Forms but is there any solution available for Xamarin MAUI.

I have tried it but with no success : https://gist.github.com/jrgcubano/4fdd6ec776c6ddeacb4d518b0355dd77

Comment: Can you show me what you have done so far?

Comment: @FreakyAli Nothing. He is obviously asking for something ready to use. Unfortunately such behavior can be achieved with bunch of platform specific code and custom control.

Comment: See the main issue here to get the Okay and Cancel events in the datepicker dialog. We do not get that in Maui somehow. We might need to use custom code to achieve that. I am just asking if somebody has done that already.

Comment: Is this a Xamarin.Forms or a .NET MAUI question? Please clean up the text and the tags

Comment: I thought to keep it as sometime people with interest in Xamarin forms can answer the question.

Comment: Hello,
Alternatively, you can use the package at the address below.
https://github.com/sebarslan/Maui.NullableDateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

> See the main issue here to get the Okay and Cancel events in the
> datepicker dialog.

The DatePicker in maui has the `OK` and `Cancel` button.

You can trigger event `DateSelected` once clicking button `OK` in the datepicker dialog.

```
        <DatePicker MinimumDate="01/01/2022" 
        MaximumDate="12/31/2022"
        Date="06/21/2022" 
        DateSelected="DatePicker_DateSelected"                                  
                    />
```

method `DatePicker_DateSelected`:

```
private void DatePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e) 
      {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the selected date is: " + e.NewDate);
      }
```

Comment: But when cancel button is clicked, it do not work